# AVAudioPlayerNode get current time is not correct

Tags: objective-c, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

I use this code to get an AVAudioPlayerNode's current time,

```
    AVAudioTime * nodeTime = _playerNode.lastRenderTime;
    AVAudioTime * playerTime = [_playerNode playerTimeForNodeTime:nodeTime];
    NSTimeInterval seconds = (NSTimeInterval)(playerTime.sampleTime / playerTime.sampleRate);
```

But, when I called this code by a `CADisplayLink`,  `playerTime.sampleTime` return `-512` or `-1024` at first time.

I don't know, is it correct?

Or is there an other way to get `AVAudioPlayerNode`'s current time real-time?

Comment: (Just for other people searching their way here, not posting this as an answer since I'm guessing.  Apple is very half-hearted with documentation on this API.)  I think this just represents buffer latency.  If you see -512 then the first frame of the player is 512 frames away from being played.  It's more useful than having it clamped to 0.